# Android Emulator is not starting properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I try to run my new Application, at initial the emulator start but after some time the process stops and it show me an error like :

```
Failed to install LoginUsingJSON.apk on device 'emulator-5556!
LoginUsingJSON] (null)
LoginUsingJSON] Failed to install LoginUsingJSON.apk on device 'emulator-5556': EOF
LoginUsingJSON] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
LoginUsingJSON] Launch canceled!
```

And after 10 or probably 15 attempts the same application runs normally.
I'm facing this problem every day regarding the emulator.
What should I do to fix this issue ?

Comment: create new AVD and try using this new AVD.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like you want to deploy the app at the moment the emulator launches, which is failing. Then after some retries (when the Emulator is up), it will succeed.

Just start the emulator once at the start of your hacking session and only when it shows the normal login screen deploy your app to it.

There is no need to shut down / restart the emulator for each deploy.

Comment: Actually this is not for this application, but it happen for the all the other application which I am making when ever i start my application it happens every time